# How can I fake Collection data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What I mean by this is I want to create it artificially.

This is for testing purposes.

But for models, it is quite simple.  I just set `defaults` I instantiate the model object and from there I can use `this.model.toJSON()` to grab the created data.

I want to use this same trick with collections.  Is there a similar way to do this with collections?  What I would want to do is have the collection create x ( 8 in this case ) copies of Model defaults.

Basically what I was doing before for models but a little bit more complex as it applies to Collections.

Here is the actual use case.  It should be simple.

```
/**Model
**/

    // name, picture, time, tweet, h_file
    var FeedRow = Backbone.Model.extend({
        Name: 'FeedRow',
        defaults: {
            name: "default",
            picture: 0,
            time: "0",
            tweet: "default",
            h_file: "default"
        }
    });

/**Collection
**/

    var FeedTable = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        Name: 'FeedTable',
        model: FeedRow
    });
```

Comment: Just use a loop to build up a list of models `var models = []; for (var i =0; i < 8;i++) { models.push(new FeedRow());}`

Comment: i would follow this way: extended some constructor from BB collection, add method like createStub and in this method add logic of creating models - like @Kyle Needham provided, then you can easily use in any instance of you upgraded constructor, like this-  myColl.createStub(8);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your FeedTable collection is constructed you could set the model on it multiple times in the initialize method.

```
var FeedTable = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    Name: 'FeedTable',
    model: FeedRow,

    initialize: function()
    {
        model  = this.model;
        models = [];

        _.times(8, function(n)
        {
            models.push(new model({id: (n + 1)}));
        });

        this.set(models);
    }
});
```

Comment: @user3294169 Using `toJSON()` will get you array with 8 objects representing the FeedRow model, each with an id from 1 to 8.

Comment: this solution worked great.  for some reason i thought there might have been something in the api, but I just took your logic and put it in a method called test() and called test() from initialize().